# Can we seek correction/suggestion for a statement of purpose (SOP)?

Tags: discussion

I went through the faq of english.stackexhange, however I did not see any instruction with regards to seeking help with SOPs. Can you tell if I can seek correction/suggestion for a statement of purpose (SOP)? Thanks.

Comment: You can always seek help here as long as your question is as specific as possible (simply asking to proofread a wall of text won't work), while at the same time not being too localized (it should be potentially useful to other people; this, admittedly, is harder to judge). It doesn't matter whether it's a SoP or a poem, as long as it is in English. See also: ["Can I ask the community to help me find errors in a text/sentence?"](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/383/) and ["How about allowing people to post entire compositions?"](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/327/)

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you're asking. Is this a general business writing question? If you have such a question (not a "please proof my text" question), you can ask it at the [Writers beta](http://writers.stackexchange.com/).